# Derivation of surface area and volume of unit $n$-sphere

Tags: calculus, geometry, recreational-mathematics

Let $S_n(R)$ and $V_n(R)$ denote the surface area and volume of an $n$-sphere with radius $R$ respectively.

It is well known that 
$$S_n(R) = \frac{n \pi^{\frac{n}{2}}R^{n-1}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\quad\text{and}\quad V_n(R) = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}R^{n}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$
where $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function:
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{z-1}\, dx.$$

> Question: How to prove the two equations above?

I was given this question during an quantitative finance interview and asked to come out with the formulas.

I managed to recite the formulas but unable to prove them.

So I am looking for derivation which can be reproduced during an interview (short and concise proof would be better).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6160/explanation-for-gamma-function-in-formula-for-n-ball-volume

Comment: Because the thickness of the $n$-sphere of radius $R+\Delta R$ less the $n$-sphere of radius $R$ is the same in all directions, the surface area is just the derivative of the volume with respect to $R$. And because $n$-volume in general scales with the $n^\text{th}$ power of the linear scaling factor, $V_n(R) = R^nV_n(1)$, So it is sufficient to show that $$V_n(1) = \frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$.